# Understanding spectral resolution for a spectrometer

Tags: instrumentation, spectrum

I am looking at this Hamamatsu mini-spectrometer, [C12880MA](https://www.hamamatsu.com/us/en/product/type/C12880MA/index.html).

The specs are,

- Spectral response range: 340 to 850
- Spectral resolution (FWHM) (typ.): 12 nm
- Number of total pixels:   288 pixels

Now the size of the band of sensor is 510 nm (850-340), how can we determine where the spectrometer's centered wavelengths, 510nm/288 pixels = 1.77nm/pixel.

Surely, I am missing something.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "centered wavelengths".   What are you trying to measure?  This device gives a spectrum, and if it measures a monochromatic source it will give a peak about 12 nm wide.

Answer (score 2):

A better way would be to take 510nm/288 which gives 1.77nm per pixel. One problem is a pixel does not equal a wavelength:
The reason being is a given wavelength does not fall on a single pixel of the sensor, it falls on many. So you would need to deconvolve the gaussian function to find out what the real intensity per bin is.

[image]
Source: https://www.hamamatsu.com/resources/pdf/ssd/mini-spectrometer_kacc9003e.pdf

Comment: The reason light spreads out is that the optics image a grating or prism onto a detector. Those optics are a spatial low pass filter with a Gaussian transfer function. As a result if you put in monochromatic light (a delta function in wavelength), it will be convolved with the Gaussian impulse response of the optics, resulting in a spot that spans the specified resolution.

Comment: True, at the end of the day I decided not to go into the details that explain how the inner workings of the spectrometer, but that is in the document

Comment: @VoltageSpike Thanks for the answer. I guess I was getting ahead of myself. What I really was trying to do was imagine what the output data would look like. Reading out the signal from the analog pin, would it give me 288 data points, where data[0] would be the signal at 340 nm, and so on? Maybe this isn't possible to answer.

Comment: So roughly every 1.77nm I would get a data point, being able to plot this I would see the spectra, yes?

Comment: For a rough sketch yes, read through the tech doc in the above post for better info.

Answer (score 0):

> IUPAC defines resolution in optical spectroscopy as the minimum wavenumber, wavelength or frequency difference between two lines in a spectrum that can be distinguished. (Wiki)

Therefore, without further processing, distinguishing two monochromatic sources will become challenging below the 12nm spectral spread of the device. Using deconvolution you can push this figure down a few times.

However, if you are interested in detecting the center position of a narrow band source (as suggested in your question, if I interpret correctly), the spectral resolution is not so important and you can do much better:

For monochromatic sources you will be able to tell their wavelength with *much better than 1 nm precision* if your intensity SNR is >>1. Imagine the image posted by Voltage Spike and moving the center frequency slightly. By doing a gaussian fit to the spectrum, you will obtain a different result for variations much smaller than 1 pixel.

It's important that the point spread size (~12 nm in this case) only equals the wavelength precision for an SNR~1. More SNR allow you obtain better and better estimations of the center frequency - *without limit*.

Comment: Spectral resolution is the ability to resolve two different spectra, not the accuracy or precision with which you can measure a single wavelength. Resolution is determined by diffraction and aberration in the focusing optics. It does not depend on SNR, although accuracy may.

Comment: I strongly disagree. The diffraction size is a meaningless number by itself..it is the resolution limit only for SNR~1. Given sufficient SNR it *is* very possible and done in practice to resolve better than the diffraction size.

Comment: The diffraction limited spot size (if this is a diffraction limited system) solely determines the spectral resolution.  It is not meaningless and it is not related to an SNR of 1.  In optics, resolution is usually quoted before deconvolution with the understanding that small improvements are possible by equalizing the transfer function of the device.

Comment: If you universally treat specs like this, you are sacrificing orders of magnitude of performance. I guess the Nobel comitee does not agree either, if they award super resolution microscopy a price for routine imaging well below the diffraction 'limit'.

Comment: I have built super resolution microscopes. This Hamamatsu spectrometer is not a super resolution microscope.  Thus, it is limited by diffraction.  Also, your first sentence in your answer is still wrong.

Comment: It is obviously not, but the principle is universal, namely feature *resolution* below the point spread size. And if you built a SRM, you know that they need  high intensity SNR (which can be accumulated over time of course) to discern fine features.

Comment: I'm downvoting since the first and last paragraph are simply wrong, while the second answers a different question than what was asked.  Only the third paragraph provides useful and accurate information.  I'm happy to reconsider if you fix these problems.

Comment: I believe the argument is due to my misusing the term spectral resolution earlier. as I understand the OP is trying to judge the precision to which different center frequencies can be measured. This does not depend on spectral resolution, hence my answer.

Comment: That is much more clear.